# How to filter a field using json_decode function in Laravel Query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to filter child records with condition if an element is present like in_array(someElement, json_decode(database_column)) but don't know exactly what will be the synatax.
I have done it through loops but I want to clear that loops and wrap it up in one query.

Till now i have done the following,

```
$projects = Project::with([
    'tasks' => function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->when($request->input('region_id') !== 'All', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('region_id', $request->input('region_id'));
        })->when($request->input('taskowner_id') !== 'All', function ($query)  {
            
        });
    }
])->get(['id', 'project_name', 'customer_id']);
```

i want to insert the folling line to that when condition of task_owner_id

```
if (in_array($taskOwnerName->emp_name, json_decode($task->task_owner, false), true)) {
    
}
```

I want to know the syntax or may be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using whereJsonContains like below

```
 $projects = Project::with([
        'tasks' => function($query) use ($taskOwnerName, $request) {
            $query->when($request->input('region_id') !== 'All', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('region_id', $request->input('region_id'));
            })->when($request->input('taskowner_id') !== 'All', function ($query) use ($taskOwnerName) {
                $query->whereJsonContains('task_owner', $taskOwnerName->emp_name);
            });
        },
    ])->get(['id', 'project_name', 'customer_id']);
```